# Back functionality in Sencha Touch

Tags: extjs

In sencha touch 2 you have routes. Do I always have to call in my controller: this.redirectTo('routeToLastView') to navigate back or is there a functionality like: history.back()?

In addition how can I find out if app running as phonegap app or webapp? Ext.browser.is.PhoneGap returns undefined.

Thank you.

Comment: try this link : https://github.com/Jackslocum/extjs-history

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you read the [History Support](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.3.1/#!/guide/history_support) guide? That's the first place I'd start.

Also the Kitchen Sink sample app uses history, so check that out.

To more accurately answer your question, you can use the generic [window.history](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.history), but you might also look at how [Ext.app.Application.history](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.3.1/#!/api/Ext.app.Application) works (specifically the [back()](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.3.1/#!/api/Ext.app.History-method-back) method).

Finally, *Ext.browser.is* should work... so if you're using PhoneGap it *should* work. Perhaps you're using Cordova, in which it would be undefined because *Ext.browser.is.Cordova* would be true.